# DynamoDb , unable to update the item dynamically using expressions

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3, python-3.7

I am trying to update Dynamo Table using expression, I am trying to generate keys dynamically. The issue looks like if they key has space in it, expressions don't evaluate properly.

Following in my update implementation:

```
        update_expression = 'SET {}'.format(','.join(f'#{p}=:{p}' for p in row_as_dict))
        expression_attribute_values = {f':{p}': v for p, v in row_as_dict.items()}
        expression_attribute_names = {f'#{p}': p for p in row_as_dict}

        if result_set.get('Item') and result_set.get('Item').get(primary_key):
            TABLE.update_item(
                Key={
                    primary_key: row_as_dict[primary_key],
                    sort_key: row_as_dict[sort_key]
                },
                UpdateExpression=update_expression,
                ExpressionAttributeValues=expression_attribute_values,
                ExpressionAttributeNames=expression_attribute_names
            )
```

if i print the values for  update_expression and expression_attribute_values and expression_attribute_names i get following output.
**update_expression**

```
SET #Ref No=:Ref No,#FT/Hot=:FT/Hot,#Irfan watch List=:Irfan watch List,#F.Soahil watchList=:F.Soahil watchList,#HR Responible=:HR Responible,#Pipeline(Adv/Ref)=:Pipeline
(Adv/Ref),#Source=:Source,#Date Submitted=:Date Submitted,#Name=:Name,#Candidate Location=:Candidate Location,#Tech =:Tech ,#Current Company=:Current Company,#Exp=:Exp,#Position being considered for=:Position being considered for,#Proj. / Gen Hiring=:Proj. / Gen Hiring,#Comments / Latest Status / Next Step=:Comments / Latest Status / Next Step,#Status=:Status,#hiring status=:hiring status,#Link to Lever=:Link to Lever,#LinkedIn Link / Resume=:LinkedIn Link / Resume,#Interview Feedback Google Doc=:Interview Feedback Google Doc,#Email=:Email
```

**expression_attribute_values**

```
{':Ref No': '1', ':FT/Hot': 'NaN', ':Irfan watch List': 'NaN', ':F.Soahil watchList': 'NaN', ':HR Responible': 'Khurram', ':Pipeline\r\n(Adv/Ref)': 'Referred', ':Source': 'Usman Khan', ':Date Submitted': '17-Dec', ':Name': 'Asif Mahmood Mughal Zain', ':Candidate Location': 'ISL', ':Tech ': 'Spark. Hadoop\r\nSQL, Big Data', ':Current Company': 'Zain Telecom', ':Exp': '18+', ':Position being considered for': 'Senior SA', ':Proj. / Gen Hiring': 'General', ':Comments / Latest Status / Next Step': 'Muhammaf Naseer      Recommneded\r\nAdeel Ashraf                Recommended\r\nFaheem Khan              Recommended\r\n\r\nAccepted offer.will join on 6 jan', ':Status': 'Joined', ':hiring status': 'Hired', ':Link to Lever': 'Link to Lever', ':LinkedIn Link / Resume': 'Asif Mehmood Mughal', ':Interview Feedback Google Doc': 'Link to Feedback', ':Email': 'some_email1@test.com'}
```

**expression_attribute_names**

```
{'#Ref No': 'Ref No', '#FT/Hot': 'FT/Hot', '#Irfan watch List': 'Irfan watch List', '#F.Soahil watchList': 'F.Soahil watchList', '#HR Responible': 'HR Responible', '#Pipeline\r\n(Adv/Ref)': 'Pipeline\r\n(Adv/Ref)', '#Source': 'Source', '#Date Submitted': 'Date Submitted', '#Name': 'Name', '#Candidate Location': 'Candidate Location', '#Tech ': 'Tech ', '#Current Company': 'Current Company', '#Exp': 'Exp', '#Position being considered for': 'Position being considered for', '#Proj. / Gen Hiring': 'Proj. / Gen Hiring', '#Comments / Latest Status / Next Step': 'Comments / Latest Status / Next Step', '#Status': 'Status', '#hiring status': 'hiring status', '#Link to Lever': 'Link to Lever', '#LinkedIn Link / Resume': 'LinkedIn Link / Resume', '#Interview Feedback Google Doc': 'Interview Feedback Google Doc', '#Email': 'Email'}
```

The Error generated is

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid key: Syntax error; key: ":hiring status"

Answer (score 1):

You can't have spaces in your attribute keys/values in the expression. So `:hiring status` needs to be something like `:hiring_status`.

Comment: Yes, i assumed so but i think documentation dont mention it any where, may be i missed it some how

Comment: "An expression attribute value must begin with a colon (:) and be followed by one or more alphanumeric characters." from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeValues.html)

Comment: I am upvoting your answer, as i guess, it aligns with what i found when exploring my issue, but in my opinion documentation is still not clear about special character.

Comment: Not sure what is unclear about "alphanumeric characters". I'm not responsible for the documentation, I'm just telling you what works.

Answer (score 0):

### Go Dynamof!

You might be very interested in [dynamof](https://github.com/rayepps/dynamof). Its a library purposed to do exactly what your trying to do. At the very least you can take a peak and check out how it handles dynamically creating all the expressions.

I suggest you take a look at the [args module](https://github.com/rayepps/dynamof/blob/develop/dynamof/core/args.py).
It has the functions that do what your trying to do. The args module gets some help from [another module (the request builder)](https://github.com/rayepps/dynamof/blob/develop/dynamof/core/builder.py) in `dynamof` that is responsible for some preprocessing of the entire action's arguments so the args module's functions get an easy to use and parse [RequestTree](https://github.com/rayepps/dynamof/blob/928f4cd4216c19a8dc8055ed983202e4f6f8d597/dynamof/core/model.py#L32) object.

### Answer...

I would just use `dynamof` - but I'm biased. If you want to write it yourself, heres a little example on how its been done straight from `dynamof`.

```py
def UpdateExpression(request: RequestTree):
    def expression(attr):
        if attr.func is not None:
            return attr.func.expression(attr)
        return f'{attr.alias} = {attr.key}'
    key_expressions = [expression(key) for key in request.attributes.values]
    key_expression = ', '.join(key_expressions)
    return f'SET {key_expression}'
```

***NOTE:*** The `attr.alias` is whats used to handle the special name cases - like spaces. Its set in the [request builder module](https://github.com/rayepps/dynamof/blob/develop/dynamof/core/builder.py) mentioned above.

*disclaimer: I wrote dynamof*